# Сервисный аккаунт в Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

По [документации](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html) Symfony сделал аутентификацию пользователей по токену. Имеется стандартный аутентификатор Symfony из коробки, который не трогался. Теперь возникла необходимость определенному кругу пользователей (например, по определенной роли) запретить авторизовываться обычным способом (логин-пароль) и оставить им только аутентификацию по токену. Видимо, в этом случае нужно переписывать стандартный аутентификатор. Как это можно сделать?

security.yaml:

```
security:
    providers:
        db:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            provider: db
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                default_target_path: /abonent_info/
                always_use_default_target_path: false
            json_login:
                check_path: /json_login

            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\TokenAuthenticator

            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /

    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    access_control:
        ...

    role_hierarchy:
        ...
```

Comment: Показывайте ваш security.yaml без него о чем то сложно говорить

Comment: @DenisStartsev добавил файл в пост

Comment: Я бы попробовал добавить еще один фаейвол в котором бы убрал form_login. И сделал бы отдельный провайдер в котором по нужным правилам ограничивал пользователей, аутентификатор переписывать по идее не нужно. В провайдерах по идее нужно будет еще context одинаковый поставить